# Parse Nested Json array in php

Tags: php, json

This JSON array comes from Android and I want to store this to the database. I parsed but not insert into the database how can I do it.

Here is my array of a customer table in SQLite database. I am sent from the mobile application and I want to store in the User table in my SQLite database

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [address] => kabul,Afghanistan
            [fname] => ahmad
            [gender] => Male
            [gfname] => jamal
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Basir ahmad
            [nationId] => 785301
            [phone] => 0772322682
            [picture] => content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A22149
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [address] => kabul
            [fname] => ali
            [gender] => Female
            [gfname] => ali
            [id] => 2
            [name] => ali
            [nationId] => 78904
            [phone] => 0772322682
            [picture] => content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A22149
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [address] => kabul,Afghanistan
            [fname] => ahmad
            [gender] => Male
            [gfname] => jamal
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Basir ahmad
            [nationId] => 785301
            [phone] => 0772322682
            [picture] => content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A22149
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [address] => kabul
            [fname] => ali
            [gender] => Female
            [gfname] => ali
            [id] => 2
            [name] => ali
            [nationId] => 78904
            [phone] => 0772322682
            [picture] => content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A22149
        )

)
```

this is the PHP code;

```
require_once '../connection/connec.php';


 $receved_data = $_POST['userData'];
  $new_array = json_decode($receved_data, true);
  print_r($new_array);

 $res = "";
 for ($i = 0; $i < $receved_data; $i++) {
    foreach ($receved_data->$i as $value) {
           $name = $value['name'];
           $fname = $value['fname'];
          $gfname = $value['gfname'];
          $nationalId = $value['gfname'];
          $gender = $value['gender'];
          $phone = $value['phone'];
          $picture = $value['picture'];
          $address = $value['address'];
          $cosId = $value['costumer_id'];
    }
     print_r(inserInToUser($conn, $name, $fname, $gfname, $nationalId, $gender, $phone, $picture, 
       $address)) ;

   }


     function inserInToUser($conn, $user_name, $user_fname, $user_gfname, $user_nationalId, 
      $user_gender, $user_phone, $user_photo, $user_address)
{
     $query = 'INSERT INTO user (name,fName,gfName,nationalID,gender,phone,picture,address)
           VALUES("' . $user_name . '","' . $user_fname . '","' . $user_gfname . '","' . 
             $user_nationalId . '","' . $user_gender . '"
            ,"' . $user_phone . '","' . $user_photo . '","' . $user_address . '")';

       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
       if ($result) {
         return "Ok";

        } else {
       return $conn->error();
        }
       }
```

Comment: What are you hoping that `for ($i = 0; $i < $receved_data; $i++) {` will do.  Especially as `$receved_data` is the JSON you are receiving.  Try just commenting this out (plus the corresponding `}`).

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: You mean how do you comment out lines?  Add `//` at the start of the line is one way.

Comment: You should use multiple insert,

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp